# Using foreach loop to echo array values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a html form with the following input tags

```html
<input type="text" name="parcelnumber[]" id="parcelnumber" class="gui-input" placeholder="Parcel Number">
<input type="text" name="section[]" id="section" class="gui-input" placeholder="Section">
```

The html form looks like so;
[image]

The user is given the ability to dynamically add extra parcel numbers.

How can I use a foreach loop to echo each Section for each Parcel numbers?

The below foreach loop is not giving me the results I want. The last section is repeated again for the first parcel loop. That is why it is not giving me the echo result I am after.

```php
$parcels = $_POST['parcelnumber'];
$sections = $_POST['section'];

foreach($parcels as $parcel) {
    foreach ($sections as $section) { }
    echo $parcel . $section . "<br>";       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, does this help?

```
$parcels = $_POST['parcelnumber'];
$sections = $_POST['section'];

foreach($parcels as $key => $parcel) {
    echo $parcel . " - " . $sections[$key] . "<br>";       
}
```

Comment: I tested your answer and it sure does give me the result I am after.

Comment: CharlesEF your answer worked perfect for me. Wish I could upvote a thousand times. Thanks alot.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the code will just iterate over all parcels and all sections. You need to define the sections for each parcel,
it should be like this

```
<input type="text" name="parcelnumber[]" id="parcelnumber" class="gui-input" placeholder="Parcel Number">
<input type="text" name="section[parcelnumber][]" id="section" class="gui-input" placeholder="Section">
```

Change the name attribute of the section input with js, so that you can map which section belongs to which parcel

and then use,

```
$parcels = $_POST['parcelnumber'];
$sections = $_POST['section'];

foreach($parcels as $parcel) {
    foreach ($sections[$parcel] as $section) { }
    echo $parcel . $section . "<br>";       
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will test your answer and get back.

Comment: I ran your code but a number of errors were returned. I am using PHP 7.2. I also changed the html attributes as you suggested.

Comment: `<input type="text" name="section['the parcel number'][0]" id="section" class="gui-input" placeholder="Section">`
`<input type="text" name="section['the parcel number'][1]" id="section" class="gui-input" placeholder="Section">`

The parcel number will be added dynamically in the name attribute in 'the parcel number' position.